# Retrieve Multiple Id Routing for web form

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, routes

Is there a way to retrieve the ids for url of such in asp.net

**http://www.someurl.com/country/{country_id}/suburb/{suburb_id}**

How do i retrieve both the id using HttpContextBase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using .NET MVC, you can achieve this with some route configuration.

In your BundleConfig/Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CountryAndSuburb",
            "country/{country_id}/suburb/{suburb_id}",
            new { controller = "Countries", action = "CountryAndSuburb" }
        );
```

The Controller:

```
    public class Countries: Controller
    {
         // GET country/{country_id}/suburb/{suburb_id}
         public ActionResult CountryAndSuburb(int country_id, int suburb_id) 
         {
             return Content(country_id.ToString() + ":" + suburb_id.ToString());
         }
    }
```

You might also consider binding to a POCO model and submitting the request as form data or JSON.  The URL might not be as RESTfully semantic in that case, though.

Comment: do{country_id} and {suburb_id} need to be the same as the method signature's parameter name?

Comment: @danial- yes, they need to match.